# Postgresql 9.5 jsonb - search a date range within an array

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called **orders** that has a jsonb column called **lineItems** that contains an array of lines, each line has a property called **closedDate**. I want to search the **orders** table and return all the records that contains a line that falls with in a specified date range.

```
[
   {productName:"shirt", price: 2.99, closedDate:1494607506041},
   {productName:"pants", price: 3.99, closedDate:1494607506041}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

[try](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) `jsonb_array_elements` - here is example:

```
t=# with b as (
  with j as (
    select
      'data'::text some_column
     ,'[
   {"productName":"shirt", "price": 2.99, "closedDate":1494607506041},
   {"productName":"pants", "price": 3.99, "closedDate":1494607506041}
]'::jsonb v
    )
  select (jsonb_array_elements(j.v)->>'closedDate')::bigint cmp,*
  from j
)
select distinct some_column,v
from b
where cmp > 1494607506040 and cmp < 1494607506042;
 some_column |                                                                      v
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 data        | [{"price": 2.99, "closedDate": 1494607506041, "productName": "shirt"}, {"price": 3.99, "closedDate": 1494607506041, "productName": "pants"}]
(1 row)
```

The above will get the line if any of array closedDate get into interval `cmp > 1494607506040 and cmp < 1494607506042`

Answer (score 0):

```
with orders (lineItens) as ( values ('
    [
       {"productName":"shirt", "price": 2.99, "closedDate":1494607506041},
       {"productName":"pants", "price": 3.99, "closedDate":1494607505041}
    ]'::jsonb
))
select lineItens
from orders
where exists (
    select 1
    from jsonb_array_elements(lineItens) e(e)
    where (e ->> 'closedDate')::bigint between 1494607506040 and 1494607506045
)
;
                                                                  lineitens                                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"price": 2.99, "closedDate": 1494607506041, "productName": "shirt"}, {"price": 3.99, "closedDate": 1494607505041, "productName": "pants"}]
```